# Adding another select clause to a multi-joined Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query that currently works and is defined as:

```
SELECT LIST_OF_SITES.SITE,
  TO_CHAR(SITE_VISIT.DATE_ - LIST_OF_ISLANDS.TIMEZONE/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') DATE_,
  LIST_OF_SITES.LATITUDE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.LONGITUDE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.REEF_ZONE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.DEPTH_BIN
  FROM GISDAT.LIST_OF_SITES
LEFT JOIN GISDAT.SITE_VISIT
ON LIST_OF_SITES.SITE = SITE_VISIT.SITE
INNER JOIN GISDAT.LIST_OF_ISLANDS
ON LIST_OF_ISLANDS.ISLAND = LIST_OF_SITES.ISLAND WHERE LIST_OF_SITES.SITE = 'TUT-229';
```

All I want to add is another select clause that selects `SITE_VISIT.HABITAT_CODE` but
If I add it right after the `LIST_OF_SITES.DEPTH_BIN`, it will produce an error saying:

```
ORA-00904: "SITE_VISIT"."HABITAT_CODE": invalid identifier.
```

Some other information that might be helpful is that I have access to all tables mentioned,
and there is also a table called `LIST_OF_HABITATS` with a `HABITAT_CODE` column as well, I am not sure if that needs to be joined somehow with the `SITE_VISIT.HABITAT_COD`E in order for it to work.

Comment: You did add a comma didn't you ? Ps  I suggest you post your problem statement (not the one that works) and table definitions to get more effective help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LIST_OF_SITES.SITE,
  TO_CHAR(SITE_VISIT.DATE_ - LIST_OF_ISLANDS.TIMEZONE/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') DATE_,
  LIST_OF_SITES.LATITUDE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.LONGITUDE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.REEF_ZONE,
  LIST_OF_SITES.DEPTH_BIN, -- added a comma here
 SITE_VISIT.HABITAT_CODE -- added habitat_code
  FROM GISDAT.LIST_OF_SITES
LEFT JOIN GISDAT.SITE_VISIT
ON LIST_OF_SITES.SITE = SITE_VISIT.SITE
INNER JOIN GISDAT.LIST_OF_ISLANDS
ON LIST_OF_ISLANDS.ISLAND = LIST_OF_SITES.ISLAND
 WHERE LIST_OF_SITES.SITE = 'TUT-229';
```

If it still throws `ORA-00904 invalid identifier` error, then be sure `SITE_VISIT` doesn't have `HABITAT_CODE` column.

In that case, you need to join the proper table, and project the column of that table.

Comment: Sorry but you were right. The column only existed on the production side and not for development. Thanks for the response!